# Can't find get-launch-1.0 from Gstreamer

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, gstreamer

I'm running on an OSX Mac, I've Installed the various packages in GStreamer 1.5.1 found here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/ .

Whenever I try to run a command with *gst-launch* I get 
`-bash: gst-launch-1.0: command not found`.
Similarly I get an error trying to run *gst-inspect*.

The framework is not present in the /System/Library/Frameworks folder after installation.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run the commands you need to install it from command line:
Search for all available options:  `brew search gst`
And install all of them using:  `brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-ffmpeg`

To make it showing in Framework, install it for iOS (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.5.1/) too. If it's still not showing up, make sure you have permission for the GStreamer framework path by running command:
`mkdir /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework`
`chown yourUserId:yourUserId /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework`
Then install it again, this worked for me.

Comment: `brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-libav`