# Installing Gstreamer-1.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, bash, osx-mavericks, homebrew, gstreamer

I want to install Gstreamer-1.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks. So I already install gstreamer-1.0-1.6.0-x86_64.pkg and gstreamer-1.0-devel-1.6.0-x86_64.pkg from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.6.0/). 
After that I tried to run something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc ! fakesink
```

But got error:

```
-bash: gst-launch-1.0: command not found
```

So how I can install and use Gstreamer-1.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873313/1162305

Try installing them with the following commands from your terminal:

```
brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-libav
```

Comment: 2 additional things: 1) instead of gst-ffmpeg, use gst-libav 2) make sure if you have the latest MacOS 10.12.2 to update brew

Answer (score 18):

The package you have downloaded from the gstreamer website install everything under the /Library/Frameworks/ directory. The following command should work on your system:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Commands/gst-launch-1.0 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`brew --prefix gstreamer`/bin/gst-launch-1.0
```