# Android Gstreamer SDK tutorial error

Tags: android, gstreamer

I'm trying to test Android Gstreamer.
So I installed and configured path [SDK](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.8.1/), got [tutorial source](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development), modify path in tutorial's Android.mk, and do ndk-build at android-tutorial-1/jni.
But I got

```
$ ndk-build
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c
GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build-arm64-v8a/libgstreamer_android.so
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/gstreamer-1.0/static/libgstcoreelements.a(libgstcoreelements_la-gstelements.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gst.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstobject.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstallocator.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstbin.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstbuffer.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstbufferlist.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstbufferpool.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstbus.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstcaps.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstcapsfeatures.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstchildproxy.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstclock.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstclock-linreg.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstcontext.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstcontrolbinding.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstcontrolsource.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstdatetime.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstdebugutils.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstdevice.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstdevicemonitor.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.a(libgstreamer_1.0_la-gstdeviceprovider.o): incompatible target
...
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gstring.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gthread.o): incompatible target
/home/potato/Android/NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/potato/Android/GST/lib/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutf8.o): incompatible target
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:27: error: undefined reference to 'gst_plugin_coreelements_register'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:70: error: undefined reference to 'g_utf8_get_char_validated'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:79: error: undefined reference to 'g_strdup_printf'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:80: error: undefined reference to 'g_string_erase'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:81: error: undefined reference to 'g_string_insert'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'g_free'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:103: error: undefined reference to 'g_strdup_printf'
...
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:540: error: undefined reference to 'g_module_open'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:544: error: undefined reference to 'g_module_symbol'
gst-build-arm64-v8a/gstreamer_android.c:548: error: undefined reference to 'g_module_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/potato/Android/GST/share/gst-android/ndk-build/gstreamer-1.0.mk:229: recipe for target 'buildsharedlibrary_arm64-v8a' failed
make: *** [buildsharedlibrary_arm64-v8a] Error 1
```

**PLUS**

When I use arm-1.9.1, arm64-1.9.1 or x86-1.9.1 then I get same message

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:ndkClean
src/main/jni/Android.mk:23: *** Target arch ABI not supported.  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkClean'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jinwoo\AppData\Local\Android\NDK/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4 mins 46.216 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

x86_64-1.9.1

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:ndkClean
src/main/jni/Android.mk:35: C:\Users\Jinwoo/AppData/Local/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-x86_64-1.9.1/share/gst-android/ndk-build//plugins.mk: No such file or directory
src/main/jni/Android.mk:39: C:\Users\Jinwoo/AppData/Local/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-x86_64-1.9.1/share/gst-android/ndk-build//gstreamer-1.0.mk: No such file or directory
src/main/jni/Android.mk:35: C:\Users\Jinwoo/AppData/Local/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-x86_64-1.9.1/share/gst-android/ndk-build//plugins.mk: No such file or directory
src/main/jni/Android.mk:39: C:\Users\Jinwoo/AppData/Local/Android/gstreamer-1.0-android-x86_64-1.9.1/share/gst-android/ndk-build//gstreamer-1.0.mk: No such file or directory
src/main/jni/Android.mk:23: *** Target arch ABI not supported.  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkClean'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jinwoo\AppData\Local\Android\NDK/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.126 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial you're using isn't actually from GStreamer, it's from a third-party, and is quite old now. I haven't been able to get it working with Android Studio, only Eclipse. If you want to use the latest Android GStreamer I'd recommend looking at [this Github project](https://github.com/sdroege/gst-player).

It should work right out of the box with GStreamer SDK 1.8.0 or higher. The only change you will need is in the build.gradle file, in the `getNdkCommandLine(ndkRoot, target)` method set the `gstRoot` variable to the path to the GStreamer SDK.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that source. I've tried to use that source, but actually I don't know how to use it.... I import it with Eclipse and modify `match_parent -> fill_parent` on main.xml file in layout folder. After that, chang version from 2.1 to 4.4.2, and plus `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />`. Finally there is no file in src folder and I have a `No Launcher activity found! The Launch will only sync the application package on the device!` error.

Comment: Or should I use Android Studio for that source??

Comment: These sources are made for Android Studio and the Gradle build system, which Eclipse doesn't use. You shouldn't be using Eclipse anymore, only Android Studio. If you need to use an existing project I recommend migrating it to Android Studio, it'll help with other headaches in the future :)

Comment: I just need a test source run at any tool(Eclipse or Android Studio). Well so..I tried to use the source that you linked. But it looks strange so I can't use it when I open or import it. Are there any other way that I should know to use it??

Comment: Download the full source that I linked, and unzip it somewhere. Open Android Studio and go to File->Open, then select the folder called 'android' (inside this folder should be an 'app' folder and a 'gradle' folder, and a file called 'build.gradle'). Then hit OK and the project should open properly

Comment: Yes, I succeed open project following your lead. Thank you so much. I have tried to solve the error about applying GST SDK.

Comment: Uhm...What architecture of GST SDK should I use among arm, arm64, x86, and x86-64?? I will plus results of running some versions.

Comment: Here is what i used to install GStreamer to make this work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807973/installing-gstreamer-1-0-on-mac-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score -1):

See [gstreamer-devel](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/), you may have missed android update

Comment: Can you tell me more detail??